# C# Create matrix using 3 different lists - using LINQ

Tags: c#, excel, linq, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have 3 different lists and I would like to create a matrix then print it on the excel sheet.

First list has client ids, second list has product ids.

Third list has objects which have client id, product id and product price.

I want to write on the excels first column client ids, on the first row product ids. Between these values I want to write product prices.

But some clients do not have some products so some cells in the middle may be empty.

How can I make a matrix using these lists?

I want to make a rectangular array [,] then print it on the excel sheet.

[image]

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: When you try *something* what output you get and how it should be instead? Or you haven't try anything yet? Why?

Comment: I know I can do this using nested 2 for-loops but I want to do this using LINQ. I tried but I could not find a way using LINQ. The image I have sent, I prepared it manually on the excel for just to imagine what I want to do.

Comment: LINQ does not have a command to make a rectangular `Array`, though you can write an extension. Would a `List<List>` or `Array<List>` do instead? In C# rectangular arrays are very limiting and not really useful in most situations, why do you want to use one?

Comment: Also, if you have an `Array [,]` what type do you expect it to hold?

Answer (score 0):

Using an extension method that adds a `ForEach` variation like the two argument `Select` variant,

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this List<T> src, Action<T, int> a) {
    for (int j1 = 0; j1 < src.Count; ++j1)
        a(src[j1], j1);
}
```

You can then do:

```
var row1 = (new[] { (object)null }).Concat(products.Select(p => (object)p.productId)).ToList();
var rest = clients.Select(c => (new[] { (object)c.clientId }).Concat(products.Select(p => prices.Where(pr => pr.productId == p.productId && pr.clientId == c.clientId).Select(pr => (object)pr.price).FirstOrDefault())).ToList()).ToList();

var ans = (new[] { row1 }).Concat(rest).ToList();

var ansm = new object[ans.Count(),ans[0].Count()];

ans.ForEach((r, ir) => r.ForEach((c, ic) => { ansm[ir, ic] = c; }));
```

And `ansm` will be a `object[,]` with `null` for empty cells.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a good fit for LINQ. The most straight forward way I could come up with using LINQ is this:

```
var clientsWithIndex = clients.Select((cid, i) => new { cid, i }).ToList();
var productsWithIndex = products.Select((pid, i) => new { pid, i }).ToList();

var grid = new object[clients.Count() + 1, products.Count() + 1];

clientsWithIndex.ForEach(ci => grid[ci.i + 1, 0] = ci.cid);
productsWithIndex.ForEach(pi => grid[0, pi.i + 1] = pi.pid);

var lookup = prices.ToLookup(x => new { x.cid, x.pid }, x => x.price);

clientsWithIndex
    .SelectMany(x => productsWithIndex, (client, product) => new { client, product })
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(x =>
        grid[x.client.i + 1, x.product.i + 1] =
            lookup[new { x.client.cid, x.product.pid }].Any()
                ? (decimal?)lookup[new { x.client.cid, x.product.pid }].Sum()
                : null);
```

If I were doing this in a more traditional way it would look like this:

```
var grid = new object[clients.Count() + 1, products.Count() + 1];
var lookup = prices.ToLookup(x => new { x.cid, x.pid }, x => x.price);

for (var p = 0; p < products.Count(); p++)
{
    grid[0, p + 1] = products[p];
}
for (var c = 0; c < clients.Count(); c++)
{
    grid[c + 1, 0] = clients[c];
    for (var p = 0; p < products.Count(); p++)
    {
        var values = lookup[new { cid = clients[c], pid = products[p] }];
        grid[c + 1, p + 1] = values.Any() ? (decimal?)values.Sum() : null;
    }
}
```

Both do the correct thing, but in this circumstance I feel that the non-LINQ approach is clearer.

Having said that though, in a strict sense the only thing that makes the first approach be considered the LINQ approach is the use of `.Select((cid, i) => new { cid, i })` and `.ToList()` - which doesn't really use a lot of LINQ. Both use `.ToLookup` which was introduced with LINQ. The `.ForEach` operation was there before LINQ.

---

I did also think that NetMage made a good little extension method, so could I combine his answer with mine to make it any cleaner.

Here's what I did:

```
var lookup = prices.ToLookup(x => new { x.cid, x.pid }, x => x.price);
Func<IEnumerable<decimal>, decimal?> nullableSum = xs => xs.Any() ? xs.Sum() : (decimal?)null;

var results =
    clients
        .Select(c => products
            .Select(p => nullableSum(lookup[new { cid = c, pid = p }]))
            .Cast<object>()
            .StartWith(c)
            .ToList())
        .ToList();

var grid = new object[results.Count(), results[0].Count()];

results.ForEach((r, ir) => r.ForEach((c, ic) => grid[ir, ic] = c));
```

---

Then I thought let's just go with the cleanest use of `ForEach` that I could. Try this:

```
var lookup = prices.ToLookup(x => new { x.cid, x.pid }, x => x.price);
Func<IEnumerable<decimal>, decimal?> nullableSum = xs => xs.Any() ? xs.Sum() : (decimal?)null;

var grid = new object[clients.Count() + 1, products.Count() + 1];

clients.ForEach((c, i) => grid[i + 1, 0] = c);
products.ForEach((p, i) => grid[0, i + 1] = p);

clients.ForEach((c, ic) =>
    products.ForEach((p, ip) =>
        grid[ic + 1, ip + 1] = nullableSum(lookup[new { cid = c, pid = p }])));
```